# How can I add images in a java file?

Tags: java, image, netbeans

I am using NetBeans, and I have a class, `/game/app.java`, and an image, `/assets/Image.jpg`. I am using the code:

```
Image img = new Image("/assets/Steve.jpg");
```

and I got this error:

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Uncompilable source code - java.awt.Image is abstract; cannot be
>   instantiated  at game.App.main(App.java:11)
>   /home/user/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java
>   returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Can anyone provide any help to fix this error?

Comment: Try `Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/Steve.jpg"));`

Answer (score 0):

As [described in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html), `Image` is abstract.

You need to instantiate a concrete subclass, e.g. [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html); however, that does not accept a filename in any of its constructors.

You can load an image from a file using [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html); various overloads exist which take `InputStream`, `File` or `URL`. `File` is probably the easiest to use:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("/assets/Steve.jpg"));
```